# Web scraping but attribute comes back as none?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, instagram

I'm trying to web-scrape off a link on an instagram post with users who have liked the post, but I get an error such as "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'". Is the reason because I would have to scroll down to get to the bottom of the instagram likers list or a complete different reason? Link is below: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cHvK.jpg.

Link im trying to web scrape off: https://www.instagram.com/p/BwTq8jahWhD/liked_by/

Packages im using is beautifulsoup, lxml and requests.

Also pretty new to Python so any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
source = requests.get('https://www.instagram.com/p/BwTq8jahWhD/liked_by/').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
body = soup.find('body')
clas = body.find('div', class_='RnEpo Yx5HN      ')             
print (clas)
```

Comment: turn off JavaScript in browser and then open your url in browser - you will see what BS/requests can see. Page uses JavaScript to display data and  BS/requests don't run JavaScript. You will need `Selenium+Python` to control web browser which can run JavaScript. Instangram has also [API](https://www.instagram.com/developer/) so maybe you don't have to scrape data from page.

Comment: @furas Alright cheers, i feel like this process isn't going to be easy T_T..

Comment: if there is API and it is for free then it is easier to use it. It should have documetation with examples andmaybe even module for python to make it easier. And when you use API then you don't have to worry that it will block your script,sends captche, etc. API sometimes has sandbox/playground - place where you can test request directly in browser to learn it.

Comment: @furas but there are limits with the API they give you, so maximum likes you could get from the API would be 1000 if i remember correctly.

Comment: I found info 200 calls per user per hour. Do you need more? It is per hour. and this gives 2800 per day. And next day you have again 2800 calls. Do you need more ? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/overview/#rate-limiting

Comment: @furas yes, i need it do be done ASAP. I'm not entirely sure but both of these methods are complicated as hell >.<